# ajax cross domain script tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce

Main.php

```
<script>
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ajax.php', 
        context: document.body,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

ajax.php

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
});
</script>
<textarea>Your content here.</textarea>
```

The problem is when `tinymce.min.js` is on the same server, it loads. But when it is on different server, it does not load.

Is there anyway that I can make it load on different server in ajax page?

Thank you.

Comment: `"The problem is when tinymce.min.js is on the same server, it loads. But when it is on different server, it does not load."` What do you mean ?

Comment: @samitha I mean the source file (JS).

Comment: you mean does the tinymce.min.js is on your server it does working right ?

Comment: @samitha Yes. If I load it from my server, it works. If load from cross domain, it does not load the script file.

Comment: @samitha I have found out the problem. It is caused by older browser. I tested on several browser and found that older browser don't work. Do you have any idea to make it work on older version of browser?

Answer (score 0):

try it like bellow

Remove http or https in the url

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

[DEMO](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried, but it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna javascript to retrieve data from a cross-domain server, you can jsonp

[Demo of using jsonp](http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/jsonp/)

you can't use ajax for fetching data from cross-domain.

Comment: Ohh Man.Did you see the comments?